# S3 File Proxy via C# Web API - PDF response data Content-Length is different between environments

Tags: c#, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm using a .NET Core Web API to authorize an HTTP request before allowing the user to load file data from an S3 bucket. Locally, my attempts to load these files work fine; however, when I try to use this same process in my staging environment, neither images nor PDF files are rendering.

On a further examination of what is going on, I have found that the Content-Length on my response messages is completely different.  When I use my local instance loading against S3, I end up with a Content-Length that is about half of that when I try to load the content via my staging environment.  Perhaps the most telling issue is that the first 2 lines of the PDF response show some differences in data values.

When loading locally, the second line of my PDF response is: %âãÏÓ

When loading from staging, the second line of my PDF response is: %ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½

Am I misunderstanding an issue related to the encoding of my response here?  What could possibly be going on that would cause such a huge difference? Even when I get to the data of the file instead of just the headers, similar differences appear to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a specific issue with API Gateway in which it can't handle binary content unless expressly mapped.  I had attempted to map the binary content data appropriately in API Gateway to the correct Content Types; however, it doesn't appear to have done anything for me.  I tried to follow along with a couple articles I found to get binary content negotiation working in API gateway, but I was unable to get it to work with the Lambda proxy functionality.

After reading through the Amazon forums, I finally found a member of the Amazon team that suggested converting a binary content stream into a base64 encoded text value.  By base64 encoding the stream on the server-side to simply work with a text value, I was able to send this to my client and simply bind to the src attribute with a "data:;base64".  This pattern has worked for me with both image and PDF content. I plan on testing it with video content in the near future.